# How to change theme light/dark with Advanced Segment

Tags: flutter

[image]
I am having a problem with the algorithm with Advanced Segment to change the screen brightness, someone can help me?

I hope someone can help me with this part, cause I don't know the logic of this part.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package and try the below code to change the app theme.

Once user click on the Light

```
 onClickLight() {
      Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.light);
    }
```

Once User click on Dark

```
onClickDark(){
  Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using addListener you can track changes in the AdvancedSegment state. You can also get the value using the controller.value

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _advancedSegmentController.addListener(() {
    // change them.
    // you can use _advancedSegmentController.value
  });
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?